# Can access a shared folder when logged in, but not with runas

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-server-2008, uac, runas

We have a medium-sized school using a Win2008R2 domain. We have several shares that are blocked except to administrators.

The problem is that if I log in as an administrator, I can access the shares through windows explorer, but if I'm logged into my regular user account and run explorer by right-clicking and doing runas, I am unable to access those shares. In fact, it seems that even though I successfully authenticate when using runas, I get none of the corresponding elevated privileges I expect.

btw, these drives are mapped in case that matters.

I'm a linux user trying to learn, implement, and then teach the other admins about separation of regular user and admin similar to su/sudo. I plan to read thoroughly on msdn about this, but if you know of any other resources that are useful for learning how to do this, that would be nice.

Comment: Got some more info. When I try to right-click and run as different user (instead of admin) and then put in my uname/pwd for my admin account, it pops up a "These files can't be opened" dialog. It says it's because of internet security settings. Why would that have anything to do with windows explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of UAC. Realize that your admin credentials != Admin privileges. While processes inherit permissions from their creator, your account under UAC only has user permissions.  To have admin permissions, you'll need the OS to create the process akin to sudo.

Just like you need to sudo, you need to **elevate** commands to get Admin access.

To elevate commands, you'll need a "Run as Admin" option.  Sadly, there isn't an easy way to do this through the UI, for your situation.

You have a few options.  You can download the "Elevation Powertoys for Vista."  They are a set of VBscripts that help elevate commandss in scripts, command lines, etc.  So you can say, type in, `elevate explorer \MyServer\MyAdminShare."

Another option, and the one I tell new employees to do is just log in with your admin account.  We have Fast User Switching turned on for our admin workstations.

But for the functionality you are looking for, I'd download the "Elevation Powertoys."

http://blogs.technet.com/b/elevationpowertoys/

It includes right click entries  for an elevated CMD prompt, Explorer and Powershell.

It also allows you to elevate Autohotkey, VBscripts, CMD scripts, and an example self elevate script, Elevate sidebar gadget, and a cross architecture(x64 invoking a x86 dll) script example.